# Create AX SSRS Report with stored procedure in Dataset

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to create a SSRS Report for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.

I created a `DataSource` to a SQL Server and now I want to create a dataset with `DataSourceType` = "Stored Procedure".

The problem is in Visual Studio (2010) I do not have the option to set the `DataSourceType` to "Stored Procedure" in the properties window and I don't know why.

[image]

[Click here to see a Screenshot from the Properties Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUQXO.png)

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: I have not tried it myself, but one of my first Google results is [AX 2012 Make SSRS Report Using SQL Stored Procedure](http://tushar-ax.blogspot.de/2015/07/ax-2012-make-ssrs-report-using-sql.html), maybe give it a try?

Comment: @FH-Inway I used this website to create my project so far. But i do not have the option  DataSourceType = "Stored Procedure" which is displayed in the 11th picture.

Comment: What version of AX do you use? The website is from July last year, so I suppose it was done on R2 or R3. If you have an earlier version, this might not work.

Comment: Ok, I just tried the tutorial with R2 and VS 2010 and I can select "Stored Procedure" as Data Source Type. Could you check if the Provider property of your ReportDatasource1 is set to SQL? I will also test this with R3, but that could take a while because I'm currently updating my R3 sandbox to CU10.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you! The Provider property wasn't SQL. Now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `Provider` property of the ReportDatasource is set to `SQL`.